# C# label color change

Tags: c#, winforms, backcolor

So I am building a very basic calorie counter. I have 3 labels which show the total calorie count, one that shows the last amount of calories I had, and one that shows the number of items i have ate.

There are 3 that add calories, and 3 that reduce the calories.
 so I was wondering how I would do this:

If the calories are above 0, the backcolor should become green, and if it is below 0, the back color should be red. I know that this is not a lot of info, and I apologize for that.  I am a noob, but that is no excuse. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

3 labels which show the total calorie count, it means that they changed.
You may use TextChanged event on label (in form designer press F4 and go to events menu).

```
private void label1_TextChanged( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        if ( this._calories < 0 )
        {
            this.lb_Main.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            this.lb_Main.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

To change a background color of a control, it is enough to set its [`BackColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor(v=vs.110).aspx) property to a color, `System.Drawing.Color.Red` for example.

For example in your case:

```
if (calori > 0)
    label1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
else
    label1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

Or:

```
label1.BackColor = (calori > 0) ? System.Drawing.Color.Green : System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
calorieCountLabel.BackColor = calories.Count > 0 ? Color.green : Color.red
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (calori < 0)
    label.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
else
    label.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
```